# angular edit details using REST($resource) Service

Tags: angularjs

I have a table with result set and there is edit option existing in each row. After clicking on the 'edit' link, i am able to populating the content on the fields.

But how do i edit the existing content using REST Service.

```
<table class="table-bordered table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>id</th>
                <th>Director</th>
                <th>genre</th>
                <th>releaseYear</th>
                <th>title</th>
                <th>Action</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr ng-repeat="result in results | orderBy:'_id'">
                <td>{{result._id}}</td>
                <td>{{result.director}}</td>
                <td>{{result.genre}}</td>
                <td>{{result.releaseYear}}</td>
                <td>{{result.title}}</td>
                <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="edit(result._id)">Edit | </a><a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="delete()">Delete</a></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
```

### controller

```
 $scope.saveContact = function(){
    //save or edit contact
  };
```

I have created in plunker.
[content EDIT using REST API](http://plnkr.co/edit/V5fFTR2AhJjvpYrVNsnd?p=catalogue)

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you're using here but you get the data using: $resource("http://movieapp-sitepointdemos.rhcloud.com/api/movies/:id",{id:'@_id'}, {
    update:{
      method:'PUT'
    }

Can't you make a POST function next to it?

Comment: I added the code in plunker, results from  http://movieapp-sitepointdemos.rhcloud.com/api/movies/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put it into work. You were close to the solution.

Here is the working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/IscPGuwagOv8xIh8RK6E?p=preview)

What i did :

### 1 - I changed your way of getting the element for the form.

**HTML**

```
  //I give the complete object instead of the id
  ng-click="edit(result)"
```

**Controller**

```
  //I prefer to pass the entire object
  $scope.edit = function(result){
    $scope.cineresultsFrm = angular.copy(result);
  };
```

**Service**

I just removed the service. It wasn't useful anymore.

### 2 - I used the method of the ressource on your object

**Controller**

```
$scope.saveContact = function(){
    //The function given to $update() is the .then() function
    $scope.cineresultsFrm.$update(function(){
      //If the update succeed i update the whole list. Could be done a better way but if you don't have any performance issues that will do the job.
      $scope.getMovies();
    });
  };
```

I also changed the way you handle the "then" in the promise. But this is just a matter of taste.

```
  $scope.getMovies = function(){
    $scope.movieResults = movie.query(function() {
      $scope.results = $scope.movieResults;
    });
  };

  $scope.getMovies();
```

Hope it helped you